# Passing a variable as to communicate in subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

How can i pass a variable password which is a user's password as a input to the popen communicate,

below is my code

```
password = payload["password"]    
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'sh', '/home/admin/temp/test1.sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(input='{0}\n'.format(password))[0]
```

this gives the following error

```
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

If i hardcode the password as this

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'sh', '/home/admin/temp/test1.sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(input=b'password\n')
```

it works fine
Please help :)

Comment: `b'{}\n'.format(password)`? The second example you specify `b""` and in the first just `""`.

Comment: Hi @EliHarold, (input=b'{}\n'.format(password)) gives this error "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'"

Comment: I see, then you need to convert it with `bytes` so `bytes('{}/n'.format(password))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `string` to `bytes`. Here is the corrected code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess

password = "password"
password_bytes = bytes(password + '\n', encoding='utf-8') # Convert string to bytes
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'sh', '/home/admin/temp/test1.sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(input=password_bytes)
```